# Asking for site technical support?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I'm taking a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655616/http-error-503-server-unavailable-with-my-godaddy-windows-ultimate-hosting-plan) and I commented that Stack Overflow is not for *personal* site technical support - but now I come to think of it, was I right to say so?  It seems that it might be an issue with either of their ends, and for that reason I thought it might have been an ask for site support.  Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Comment: I think the main problem with the question is that is doesn't have anywhere near enough details to actually be able to answer it

Answer (score 2):

The question is off-topic. Mostly because it is overly generic - nothing specific about it.

If the OP had *identified* the actual issue and the associated code and asked about *that*, it would have been OK (topic wise).

As it stands, it *might* be a good fit for Server Fault (again, topic wise only, I think it suffers from a few quality issues that make it a bad question in general for SE sites).